# Automatically Android Studio changes the background of every projects

Tags: android, android-studio, background-color

I'm new into android!
my question is about this : automatically Android Studio make the background of every projects to black.
i have tried to change app theme , Colors & styles but it doesn't came back like previous one.

[image]

> android studio version: 2.2.2.0
>   BuildTools version: 25.0.0

Comment: can you post your style.xml code

Comment: you need to change the theme of the project from `NoActionBar` Dark to Light ... Check this [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/fDL1qAg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not the color of your app or project its the color of layout editor preview.
try to run in emulator or real devices you will find it works perfect.

another thing is as @maven provided the real cause in comment to change the view you may also follow that to change the theme of editor preview in android studio. And select any one you want by clicking on NoActionBar and select any light theme from holo or appcompact or mytheme as supposed your project theme.

[image]